# Работа с массивами PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

В постгре есть такой тип как массив например String[]. в заполненной таблице этот тип выглядит так: {qwerty,asdfgh,zxcvbn}. В коде, после запроса, я и получаю строку типа {qwerty,asdfgh,zxcvbn}. Можно ли в java преобразовывать ее в любую структуру, массив итп.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Копайте в сторону [java.sql.Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html) и [ResultSet.getArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getArray%28java.lang.String%29). Есть даже всякие примеры в интернете по теме. Например, [тут в последнем листинге](http://tech.valgog.com/2009/02/getting-arrays-from-postgresql-database.html) берут String[].

Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
    Connection connection = ...;
    PreparedStatement pst = ...;
    ResultSet rs = ...;

    // SELECT
    String[] myField = (String[]) rs.getArray("MY_FIELD").getArray();

    // UPDATE
    pst.setArray(1, connection.createArrayOf("CHARACTER VARYING", new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не мог додуматься до 2го getArray