# Получить массив из PostgreSQL в Java

Tags: java, массивы, база-данных, postgresql, intellij-idea

Получаю наименование столбцов в массив из PostgreSQL 15 следующим образом:

```
select array_agg(column_name)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'qwe_asd' and data_type='boolean';
```

Массив приходит в данном типе:

```
{общее_недомогание,сухость_першение,кашель_сухой_мокрый,голос_хриплый_беззвучный,боль_при_глотании,головная_боль,температура_тела,охриплость_афонией,утомляемость_гортани,кашель_мокротой,дискомфорта_гортани,сухой_кашель,жжение_горле,кашель_обострении,слизистая_густой_слизью,откашливание_прожилками_крови}
```

Вопрос, возможно ли почить стразу массив строк в Java?

---

Дело в том что я получаю результат не сразу массивом, а таблицей. Ну я так думаю.

После выполнения

```
String [] qw = (String[]) result.getArray(1).getArray();
```

или

```
String [] qw = (String[]) result.getArray("array_agg").getArray();
```

Я получаю:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

---

Попробовал вот так:

```
select array_to_string(array_agg(column_name),',') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'qwe_asd' and data_type='boolean'
```

выводит уже без скобок через запятую, но:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Запрос не вернул результатов.
```

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Работа с массивами PostgreSQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/60937/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-postgresql)

Comment: Только вот у меня эта строка выдает Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')